# Sublime Text keep highlighting area instead of commenting it out

Tags: sublimetext3, comments

For some reason when I try to comment in Sublime Ctrl+/ it will sometimes (not always) highlight the area like this. I'm just wondering if anyone knows what this is and if there's a way to stop sublime from doing it.

[image]

Comment: Does it only happen when the line is already commented?

Comment: Please put together a [mcve] so we can try to replicate it. Include a snippet of code (as text, not an image) and the language you are using, as well as the version of Sublime you have. Please also list any plugins you are using, as well as the color scheme you have active.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz It sometimes happens when uncommenting and some times when commenting. In this instance, it happened, then I pressed ctrl+/ again and it commented after that.

Comment: @MattDMo The code should affect is as it's the editor. It happens with any type of code I've tried. I use primary ruby and JavaScript in sublime. But it sometimes happens with other languages too. The only plugin I have is Babel JS, but I doubt it's that as it happens with ruby too.  As for version I have Sublime Text 3. 3211 X64 shows up when I search it so I assume that it's 3.2.11 or something like that.

Comment: I asked for the code so I can have something to copy and paste, and don't have to waste time retyping what you wrote. Just use whatever is in your screenshot.

Comment: @MattDMo Here's some the typescript from the image

```const saveLineItem = (orderId: number, orderNo: number, orderItem: OrderItem, giftCardNumber?: string) => {
    // After the order is saved, save the lineItem
    const nextLineItem = calcNextLineItem(order.orderItems);
    return saveOrderItemMutation.mutateAsync({
      ...orderItem, orderNo, orderId, giftCardNumber, 
      lineItem: (orderItem.lineItem ? orderItem.lineItem : nextLineItem)
    })```

Comment: I can't replicate the behavior, so I'm not sure what is going on. If you're using the [`TypeScript`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript) plugin for syntax highlighting, it's possible one of the other components in the package is messing around with the highlighting - linters and code intelligence plugins can do that. It could be just about anything.

Comment: @MattDMo  that's too bad, I'll keep trying things and see if I can figure out why it's doing that.

Comment: That green color looks an awful lot like an [incremental diff added line](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/incremental_diff.html#inline_diffs), and the default key binding for toggling diff hunks is `Ctrl+K`,`Ctrl+/`, while comment toggling is `Ctrl+/` by default. I doubt that's a co-incidence. Next time this happens, put the cursor in the green area, right click and see if `Hide Diff Chunk` appears in the menu.

Comment: @OdatNurd Oh my word, that's it. I guess I kept hitting the ctrl+k because in some other editors that I used that's the comment shortcut. I guess I wasn't putting it together that it was only happening when I accidently pressed ctrl+k first, I thought the comment was just breaking randomly. Also, that Hide Diff works to get rid of it, thank you so much :D.
Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: @MyNameIsntBob Answer added; I also threw in a bit more information and background on what's happening as a whole as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing here is a diff hunk from the [incremental diff](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/incremental_diff.html) functionality of Sublime Text, which tracks changes made to files and allows you to see what those changes are (and to revert them individually). It's controlled by the following setting (with the default value):

```json
    // Indicate modified lines in the gutter
    // - true: Enables modified line indicators on all files
    // - "auto": Enables modified line indicators on tracked files within Git
    // - false: Disables modified line indicators
    "mini_diff": true,
```

For files tracked by `git`, the following setting controls what the diff is calculated against (for files not tracked by `git`, the diff is against the file ***as it was when it was originally opened***, so saving the file does not clear the indicators).

```json
    // This setting determines whether tracked Git files should be diffed
    // against the index or HEAD.
    // Valid values are "index" or "head"
    "git_diff_target": "index",
```

This functionality encompasses tracking the changes, showing you indicators in the gutter, navigating between changes and showing you an inline diff that shows you how the change modified the document.

In your case, what you're seeing here is a line that you added being highlighted in a diff hunk, which can accidentally happen because the default key binding sequence for toggling the diff hunk is <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+/</kbd> which includes <kbd>Ctrl+/</kbd> -- the key used to toggle the state of the diff hunk.

You can use that key binding or the items in the context menu to re-toggle the state of the hunk off.

Information on the feature in general as well as the default key bindings, can be found in the official documentation, which is available at: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/incremental_diff.html

Comment: Nice answer. I had a suspicion that the highlighting looked like a diff mark, but I was missing the keybinding bit.